# Using xmlstarlet to remove xml node based on matching string?

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to remove everything between `<AdditionalApplication>` and `</AdditionalApplication>` IF it contains the phrase **"Pixel Perfect"** I'm having a heck of a time removing an entire block based on matching a single tag.

The first `<AdditionalApplication>...</AdditionalApplication>` would be removed, but not the second because it doesn't match a specific xml tag within the parent block. Any quick fixes for this using xmlstarlet?

```
<AdditionalApplication>
  <Id>63463edb-28fa-4029-9405-1360b9eb092a</Id>
  <PlayCount>0</PlayCount>
  <GameID>1b9277aa-4c31-467b-bcad-3cbca7589d08</GameID>
  <ApplicationPath>eXo\eXoDOS\!dos\themist\Extras\Alternate Launcher.bat</ApplicationPath>
  <AutoRunAfter>false</AutoRunAfter>
  <AutoRunBefore>false</AutoRunBefore>
  <Name>Pixel Perfect &amp; Shader Options</Name>  // BECAUSE THIS LINE MATCHES, Remove entire <AdditionalApplication> ... </AdditionalApplication> block
  <UseDosBox>false</UseDosBox>
  <UseEmulator>false</UslaeEmutor>
  <WaitForExit>false</WaitForExit>
  <SideA>false</SideA>
  <SideB>false</SideB>
  <Priority>0</Priority>
</AdditionalApplication>

<AdditionalApplication>
  <Id>f1dd929c-3d1a-461a-a943-3e7ad99e4426</Id>
  <PlayCount>0</PlayCount>
  <GameID>1b9277aa-4c31-467b-bcad-3cbca7589d08</GameID>
  <ApplicationPath>eXo\eXoDOS\!dos\themist\Extras\mist-refcard.pdf</ApplicationPath>
  <AutoRunAfter>false</AutoRunAfter>
  <AutoRunBefore>false</AutoRunBefore>
  <CommandLine />
  <Name>Reference Card</Name>
  <UseDosBox>false</UseDosBox>
  <UseEmulator>false</UseEmulator>
  <WaitForExit>false</WaitForExit>
  <Developer />
  <Publisher />
  <Region />
  <Version />
  <Status />
  <SideA>false</SideA>
  <SideB>false</SideB>
  <Priority>0</Priority>
</AdditionalApplication>
```

Comment: Is "Pixel Perfect" always part of node "Name"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should get you there:

```
xml ed -d  '//AdditionalApplication[.//Name[contains(text(),"Pixel Perfect")]]'  myfile.xml
```